# Prevent Direct Access to a php file and allow only one domain

Tags: php

First of all I apologize if this question is already asked as I searched and couldn't found the exact question and answer.

So let's start I want to force .mp3 files to download instead of playing therefore I use the following code in download.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Download the mp3 file.
 */
$file_name = $_GET["filename"];
$file_url = $_GET["fileurl"];

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-type: application/mp3');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

So when users click on a link with destination http://www.example.com/download.php?filename=example.mp3&url=http://www.example.com/example.mp3 the are able to save the file.

So what I want is to prevent direct access to file http://www.example.com/download.php

and allow users to download files using url: http://www.example.com/download.php?filename=example.mp3&url=http://www.example.com/example.mp3

Comment: The question is wrong somehow!! what do you mean exactly by prevent direct access to that file?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to review the answers that have been submitted to your question, and 'Accept' the answer that you feel is the best solution to your question (if any) - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server you can make use .htaccess to deny access to some files.

Here is an example you can add to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files /example.mp3>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Actually I only want to deny direct access to download.php file in the other hand I want give the users abality to download files using this url: www.example.com/download.php?filename=example.mp3&url=http://www.example.com/example.mp3  I tired .htaccess but it didn't work form me I used Deny from all allow from example.com it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
if($_GET['filename'] == ''){
         header("Location: http://someLocation.com/");
    }
```

Comment: I am totally could you please tell me how to put this code in download.php file which the code is listed above.

Comment: Put that piece of code at the top of download.php. I think it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First off, blindly calling `readfile()` from a parameter defined in the request presents a huge security risk.

My recommendation is to accept filename only, then build a full filepath containing the filename and the path to your mp3 folder.  Then ensure that the file exists, then do the `readfile()`

*NOTE* Your mp3 folder should be outside of your public html folder, or if not, at least configure your web server with an access rule that prevents direct access to the folder.

Secondly, the only way to prevent access to your php file with no parameters is to use a rewrite rule (if your web server supports it)

A more simple approach might be to check to see if there is no filename parameter, then have a default behavior, i.e. redirect to homepage, etc.  This can also be the default behavior specified file doesn't exist.

Lastly, I have a GitHub project that you might find useful - for ideas if nothing else:

https://github.com/iNamik/PHP-Download-Tracker